# hive condition in shell script not working as expected

Tags: sql, shell, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Condition within Hive query in shell script not working properly

Wrote a shell script to send out email alert based on the condition in the outcome of a query, but no matter what happens, only the 2nd part (else part) always gets sent, no matter the outcome of the variable. Please kindly help to check. Below is the script:

```
#!bin/sh

strata=$(impala connection string -q "SELECT calendar, COUNT(*) row_count FROM TABLE   
 WHERE calendar = CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now() - interval 1 days), 'yyyyMMdd') AS INT)
GROUP BY calendar
 ORDER BY calendar DESC;")
 
if [ $strata -eq 0 ] ;then
echo -e 'The table HAS NOT been refreshed today, kindly hold' |  mailx -s 'Alerting:Refresh_Status' -c email.address -- email.address
else
echo -e The number of records is $strata |  mailx -s 'Alerting: Refresh_Status' -c email.address -- email.address 
fi
```

The output of the variable will either be `0` or the number of records in the table, and email will be sent based on that. But the else part is the only one that gets sent regardless of the result.

Comment: echo "$strata" ?

Comment: is `impala` actually `impala-shell`? If yes, I think 0 will indicate successful execution of -q query, and non-zero -- an error.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I'm wrong, I think the strata variable will contain the result of your query hence the if statement in your script will jump to the else state because the result is not equal 0.
I think the query should be like this.

> SELECT COUNT(*) row_count FROM TABLE
> WHERE calendar = CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now() - interval 1 days), 'yyyyMMdd') AS INT)

You just need to exclude the calendar from your select statement.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).